# Is it ok to declare destructor as private?

Tags: php, oop

Some of my classes declare their constructors as private because an object of such class is only allowed to be created by a static method of the class. May I also declare destructors of such classes as private to keep it symmetric, is it safe?

**EDIT**: Ok, seems like this is simply not possible:

```
Fatal error: Call to private AClass::__destruct() from context '' in /script on line 0
```

(the context is empty and there's no such thing as line 0). For some reason I used to think that the PHP runtime is almighty and can destruct anything it wants.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In php the `__destruct` magic method *must* be `public`. The method will automatically be called externally to the instance. Declaring `__destruct` as `protected` or `private` will result in a warning and the magic method will not be called.

There's no symmetry necessary, as you should never explicitly call `__destruct`.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to private Foo::__destruct() from context  when declaring as private

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you are implementing the singleton pattern. In this pattern constructor must be private and you have a static method that returns an instance of the class. If there's no instance, this static method will create it and return it.

If you set destructor access to private, you don't allow to other classes or functions to destruct that instance and this could be inconsistent if in a point of execution of your application you will not use that instance any more. There's no reason to set destructor to private because even if it's public, the static method is capable to return a new instance if there's no one.

Comment: They will still have to be careful with synchronization of the singleton's pointer/slot in the class definition across the static getter and the destructor.  Don't want the static getter to return the singleton just before it is destroyed.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the singleton pattern is a very bad pattern in most (not all) cases and introduces many design problems. Also not possible to do proper unit testing with them.

Comment: It's implemented that way to simulate function overloading with multiple static methods when constructing an object of the class (overloading is not supported in PHP)